# Not able to change svg elements color by looping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to change the color of svg elements by comparing the id's of the elements with an array. I'm getting the correct comparison results by looping the id's of all the available elements and comparing them with the array data. However, I'm not able to dynamically color the compared element.

This is what I have tried so far: [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-change-color-5rlgk)

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import NewTestColor from "./NewTestColor";

const App = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      id: "D",
      hmc: "",
      lmc: "low"
    },
    {
      id: "B",
      hmc: "high",
      lmc: ""
    },
    {
      id: "A",
      hmc: "high",
      lmc: ""
    },
    {
      id: "C",
      hmc: "",
      lmc: "low"
    }
  ];

  const addEventListener =
    ("mouseup",
    (e) => {
      // Let's pick a random color between #000000 and #FFFFFF
      const rnd = Math.round(Math.random() * 0xffffff);

      // Let's format the color to fit CSS requirements
      const fill = "#" + rnd.toString(16).padStart(6, "0");

      // Let's apply our color in the
      // element we actually clicked on
      e.target.style.fill = fill;
      const id = e.target.getAttribute("id");

      console.log(id);
      console.log(fill);
      //  console.log(data);
    });

  // const Ndata = data.filter(task => task.hmc === "high")
  // .map(filteredData  => {filteredData.id}, {filteredData.hmc}, {filteredData.color}  )

  const FilteredData = data.filter((e) => e.hmc.includes("high"));
  const OnlyIp = FilteredData.map((e) => `${e.id} ${e.hmc}`);

  // console.log(OnlyIp)
  console.log(FilteredData);

  return (
    <div>
      <NewTestColor onClick={addEventListener} items={FilteredData} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is if you define onClick as a prop on a component you defined it does not work. You need to add it to an actual element like `svg`.

Change the `NewTestColor` to pass to `onClick` function to outer `svg`

```
const NewTestColor = ({ onClick }) => (
  <svg viewBox="0 0 210 297" height={500} width={500} onClick={onClick}>
    ...
    ...
    ...
  </svg>
);
```

And the `addEventListener` function in `App.js` should look like below.

```
  const addEventListener = (e) => {
    // Let's pick a random color between #000000 and #FFFFFF
    const rnd = Math.round(Math.random() * 0xffffff);

    // Let's format the color to fit CSS requirements
    const fill = "#" + rnd.toString(16).padStart(6, "0");

    // Let's apply our color in the
    // element we actually clicked on
    e.target.style.fill = fill;
    const id = e.target.getAttribute("id");

    console.log(id);
    console.log(fill);
    //  console.log(data);
  };
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-change-color-forked-78dke?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @bob, check this out !!

Comment: Kindly ignore the onClick event. I was just trying with it for some other purpose. I need to change the color of the svg elements based on the API data I'm going to receive in my reactjs app. The sample data in App.js represents my API data. The id's from this API data will be compared with svg elements and if it matches then color.